# Why are wait() and notify() declared in Java's Object class?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Why are the `wait()` and `notify()` methods declared in the `Object` class, rather than the `Thread` class?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because, you wait on a given Object (or specifically, its monitor) to use this functionality.

I think you may be mistaken on how these methods work.  They're not simply at a Thread-granularity level, i.e. it is *not* a case of just calling `wait()` and being woken up by the next call to `notify()`.  Rather, you always call `wait()` on a specific object, and will only be woken by calls to `notify` **on that object**.

This is good because otherwise concurrency primitives just wouldn't scale; it would be equivalent to having global namespaces, since any calls to `notify()` anywhere in your program would have the potential to mess up *any* concurrent code as they would wake up any threads blocking on a `wait()` call.  Hence the reason that you call them on a specific object; it gives a context for the wait-notify pair to operate on, so when you call `myBlockingObject.notify()`, on a private object, you can be sure that you'll only wake up threads that called wait methods in your class.  Some Spring thread that might be waiting on another object will not be woken up by this call, and vice versa.

Edit: Or to address it from another perspective - I expect from your question you thought you would get a handle to the waiting thread and call `notify()` on *that Thread* to wake it up.  The reason it's not done this way, is that you would have to do a lot of housekeeping yourself.  The thread going to wait would have to publish a reference to itself somewhere that other threads could see it; this would have to be properly synchronized to enforce consistency and visibility.  And when you want to wake up a thread you'd have to get hold of this reference, awaken it, and remove it from wherever you read it from.  There's a lot more manual scaffolding involved, and a lot more chance of going wrong with it (especially in a concurrent environment) compared to just calling `myObj.wait()` in the sleeping thread and then `myObj.notify()` in the waker thread.

Comment: This doesn't begin to answer why you can wait on ANY object. Why wasn't there a specific Lock class or type? Or maybe a marker interface?

Comment: "...potential to mess up any concurrent code as they would wake up any threads blocking on a wait() call..."  That's OK as long as "mess up" means "limit the performance."  It shouldn't actually break anything because one _always_ calls wait() in a loop until the condition one is waiting for becomes true.

Comment: @mjaggard I think the answer by Solomon here answers that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293039/731752. It boils down to "it didn't have to."

Answer (score 11):

The most simple and obvious reason is that any Object (not just a thread)
can be the monitor for a thread. The wait and notify are called on the
monitor. The running thread checks with the monitor. So the wait and notify methods are in Object and not Thread

Answer (score 8):

Because only one thread at a time can own an object's monitor and this monitor is what the threads are waiting on or notifying. If you read the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for `Object.notify()` and `Object.wait()` it's described in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism of synchronization involves a concept - monitor of an object. When wait() is called, the monitor is requested and further execution is suspended until monitor is acquired or InterruptedException occurs. When notify() is called, the monitor is released.

Let's take a scenario if wait() and notify() were placed in Thread class instead of Object class. At one point in the code, `currentThread.wait()` is called and then an object `anObject` is accessed.

```
//.........
currentThread.wait();
anObject.setValue(1);
//.........
```

When currentThread.wait() is called, monitor of `currentThread` is requested and no further execution is made until either the monitor is acquired or InterruptedException occurs. Now while in waiting state, if a method `foo()` of another object `anotherObject` residing in `currentThread` is called from another thread, it is stuck even though the called method `foo()` does not access `anObject`. If the first wait() method was called on `anObject`,  instead of the thread itself, other method calls (not accessing `anObject`) on objects residing in the same thread would not get stuck.

Thus calling wait() and notify() methods on Object class(or its subclasses) provides greater concurrency and that's why these methods are in Object class, not in Thread class.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the other answers use the word "monitor", but none explain what it means.

The name "monitor" was coined way back in the 1970s, and it referred to an object that had its own intrinsic lock, and associated wait/notify mechanism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29

Twenty years later, there was a brief moment in time when desktop, multi-processor computers were new, and it was fashionable to think that the right way to design software for them would be to create object-oriented programs in which *every object* was a monitor.

Turns out not to have been such a useful idea, but that brief moment happens to be exactly when the Java programming language was invented.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#57537) for an explanation of wait and notify.

It would be better to avoid these however in your applications and use the newer [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

I will put it in a simple way:

To call wait() or notify() you need to own the object monitor - this means wait() or notify() needs to be present in the synchronized block

```
synchronized(monitorObj){
monitorObj.wait()  or even notify
}
```

Thats the reason these methods are present in object class

Answer (score 0):

This is because,these methods are for inter thread communication and interthreadcommunication happens by using locks, but locks are associated with objects.hence it is in object class.