# Methods in Thread class and Object class

Tags: java, multithreading

We have `start(), run() and join() methods` with threads as we use them on thread objects, these methods are under `Thread class`.

And `wait(), notify(), and notifyAll()` which we use also with Thread object but these methods are under `Object class`.

I Am thinking why there is need to define these methods under Object class as we call them only with `Threads`?. We know whenever we call `wait()` object goes to the wait state waiting for a Shared resource/a condition to satisfy but this can only happen in threaded environment.

So the question is why there is need to put these methods under Object class?

Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: The most basic reason is that for wait(), notify(), and notifyAll() to be useful multiple threads have to execute them using the same object.

Comment: Don't thread on me. You're missing a bunch of "h". Objects can be the subject of waits/notifications even if they're not `Thread`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods `wait()`/`notify()`/`notifyAll()` belong to object because they work with this object as with monitor.

### Similar questions:

- [Why wait ,notify and notifyAll Methods are in Object Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516038/why-wait-notify-and-notifyall-methods-are-in-object-class)
- [Why are wait() and notify() declared in Java's Object class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769489/why-are-wait-and-notify-declared-in-javas-object-class)
- [why wait/notify/notifyAll methods are not synchronized in java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019745/why-wait-notify-notifyall-methods-are-not-synchronized-in-java)

*Try to seach for same questions on SO before asking...*

Comment: @zvzdhk.. Thanks, sure will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Each Java object has a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) associated with it. The functions that you refer to operate on the object's monitor. This is the reason they need to be defined under `Object` (they *could* have been made `static` members of some other class, but then they would need to take an argument of type `Object` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Object class is the super class for all java classes.The methods in Object we can use in any class for synchronization.