# Do successive calls to wait(millisec) make a thread wait longer?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If I keep calling wait(1000) on a thread, does that make it wait longer or is it going to wait only 1000 milli-seconds?

I mean if I call it the first time and then a second time, would that make it wait 2000 milli-seconds or just 1000?

Comment: Why would you think it doesn't wait when you call `wait()`?

Comment: Use higher values and try it yourself.

Comment: Have you read the javadocs on `Object.wait(...)`?  What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to Object.wait(int millis) blocks execution for at most n milliseconds. A second call blocks again for at most the respective time, hence,

```
obj.wait(1000);
obj.wait(1000);
```

makes your program wait for at most 2 seconds. Read the JavaDoc to see under which conditions the time can be shorter.

However, I'm not sure you really want to use wait(). Read [about the intended usage of wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769489/why-are-wait-and-notify-declared-in-javas-object-class). Maybe you should have a look at Thread.sleep(int millis). I thinks this could be what you actually want to use.